# Detecting white image background with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, css, image, image-processing

Is it possible with PHP (alternatively JS or something similiar) to detect if an image has a mostly white background?

It is because where I display my images there's a white background. And some images have a dark or colorful background, but some are white or mostly white. And I have a css class called `img-shadow` that adds a shadow to an image. So I would like to add that only if the background of an image is white or mostly white.

Here's an example to show you what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Could you not use a histogram? What is your main objective? Is it to detect images with a border or images that are mostly white? I would say that both of those images are mostly white.

Comment: I just thought about "I just need to find out how to count the white pixels of an image", calculate them in percent and then decide to add the class or not. And I totally forgot about the histogram function of cameras that exactly do that. So I just need to find out how to do this in php/js. Yes, it's the same image. As I said I just added the class to that left image. Because you asked for the reason: It is because you won't see the border of an image with a mostly white or fully white background on the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even there are a lot of pitfalls in whole process, I would choose doing it using PHP.

Firstly, answer yourself following:

- What exactly will be *mostly white background*? Does RGB(250,250,250) still counts?
- Does PNG with alpha channel counts ([RGBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space))?
- Does image with light/bright yellow counts?
- Does image with black border (frame) and white center will stil counts as white
  background?
- Will user be able to upload image?

You have to:

1. Load image
2. [get histogram](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagehistogram.php)
3. Analyze according to your rules
4. Add meta info about particular image and generate css class on output.

On top of that I suggest:

- Some sort of result caching or metadata storing so on every script execution images won't be analyzed
- Check if image has border (develop algorythm by looking on sides of picture)
- Treat alpha channel same as white color (maybe dark logo with round corners - no white color)